# Azure ADB2C RESTful API Sign In error: "Error granting access to your user, please try again later. Validation error: Email is mandatory."

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

in order to validate if a user email exists in a given database before sign he in I'm using a RESTful API technical profile.

When I perform the sign-in flow using external IdPs (e.g. Google, Facebook, etc) it works like a charm, however, with local account sign-in flow (e.g. login and password) I get the exception above;

Here's a few information I got from Application Insights:

```json
{
        "Kind": "Headers",
        "Content": {
            "UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint": "urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights",
            "CorrelationId": "97c526e1-96cd-45b6-8dd9-dfe26f26dfa5",
            "EventInstance": "Event:API",
            "TenantId": "foo",
            "PolicyId": "B2C_1A_V2_AccountLink_SUSI"
     


"Kind": "HandlerResult",
        "Content": {
            "Result": true,
            "RecorderRecord": {
                "Values": [
                    {
                        "Key": "SendErrorTechnicalProfile",
                        "Value": "OpenIdConnectProtocolProvider"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": "Exception",
                        "Value": {
                            "Kind": "Handled",
                            "HResult": "80131500",
                            "Message": "Error granting access to your user, please try again later. Validation error: Email is mandatory.",
                            "Data": {
                                "IsPolicySpecificError": false
                            },
                            "Exception": {
                                "Kind": "Handled",
                                "HResult": "80131500",
                                "Message": "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.",
                                "Data": {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

The `Statebag` + additional HTTP request info:

```json
 "Statebag": {
                "Complex-CLMS": {
                    "signInName": "foo@gmail.com",
                    "objectId": "aaaaaaa-bbbbbb-4b0c-be57-852ca738e337",
                    "authenticationSource": "localAccountAuthentication",
                    "termsOfUseConsentRequired": "False",
                    "extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime": "12/2/2021 2:30:09 PM",
                    "currentTime": "12/2/2021 2:39:14 PM",
                    "currentUserIdentities": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[Microsoft.Cpim.Data.UserIdentity]",
                    "signInNames.emailAddress": "foo@gmail.com",
                    "displayName": "Raphael Silva",
                    "givenName": "Raphael ramos",
                    "surname": "silva",
                    "issuers": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.String]"
                },
                "PROT": {
                    "c": "2021-12-02T14:39:16.1594338Z",
                    "k": "PROT",
                    "v": "AAD Request to https://graph.windows.net/<foo>/users/<bar>?api-version=1.6 using method GET as request body is malformed.\r\nResponse: \n{\"odata.metadata\":\"https://graph.windows.net/<foo>/$metadata#directoryObjects/@Element\",\"odata.type\":\"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User\",\"objectType\":\"User\",\"objectId\":\"<bar>\",\"deletionTimestamp\":null,\"accountEnabled\":true,\"ageGroup\":null,\"assignedLicenses\":[],\"assignedPlans\":[],\"city\":null,\"companyName\":null,\"consentProvidedForMinor\":null,\"country\":null,\"createdDateTime\":\"2021-12-02T14:30:28Z\",\"creationType\":\"LocalAccount\",\"department\":null,\"dirSyncEnabled\":null,\"displayName\":\"Raphael Silva\",\"employeeId\":null,\"facsimileTelephoneNumber\":null,\"givenName\":\"Raphael ramos\",\"immutableId\":null,\"isCompromised\":null,\"jobTitle\":null,\"lastDirSyncTime\":null,\"legalAgeGroupClassification\":null,\"mail\":null,\"mailNickname\":\"<foo>\",\"mobile\":null,\"onPremisesDistinguishedName\":null,\"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier\":null,\"otherMails\":[],\"passwordPolicies\":\"DisablePasswordExpiration\",\"passwordProfile\":null,\"physicalDeliveryOfficeName\":null,\"postalCode\":null,\"preferredLanguage\":null,\"provisionedPlans\":[],\"provisioningErrors\":[],\"proxyAddresses\":[],\"refreshTokensValidFromDateTime\":\"2021-12-02T14:30:28Z\",\"showInAddressList\":null,\"signInNames\":[{\"type\":\"emailAddress\",\"value\":\"r.r.raphael.silva@gmail.com\"}],\"sipProxyAddress\":null,\"state\":null,\"streetAddress\":null,\"surname\":\"silva\",\"telephoneNumber\":null,\"thumbnailPhoto@odata.mediaEditLink\":\"directoryObjects/6207c4d7-8e54-4b0c-be57-852ca738e337/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/thumbnailPhoto\",\"usageLocation\":null,\"userIdentities\":[],\"userPrincipalName\":\"<foobar>\",\"userState\":null,\"userStateChangedOn\":null,\"userType\":\"Member\",\"extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_residentialPostcode\":\"<foo>\",\"extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_termsOfUseConsentVersion\":\"V1\",\"extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_termsOfUseConsentChoice\":\"AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentYes\",\"extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_termsOfUseConsentDateTime@odata.type\":\"Edm.DateTime\",\"extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_termsOfUseConsentDateTime\":\"2021-12-02T14:30:08.7498164Z\",\"extension_9614eff520454054b6d79fbe0c7a5491_haspassword\":true}\r\n",
                    "p": false
                }
            }
        }
```

Finally, the RESTapi technical profile:

```xml
 <!-- B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions -->
 <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-AuthB2CSignIn">
          <DisplayName>Get User roles from the database</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <!-- Set the ServiceUrl with your own REST API endpoint -->
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{config:SignInFunction}</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />

          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Roles" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: I feel you might have set email as mandatory in your rest api. Can you check if you are getting value for the email attribute. It seems the value is stored in "signIn.EmailAddress" and "signInName". Can you try with  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signIn.EmailAddress" /> instead of <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if below points can be worked aorund along with the commented one

1. To enable authentication by the local account sign-in against the Azure AD B2C directory, you must add the Identity Experience Framework(IEF) applications to the Azure AD B2C directory and then configure these IEF applications with the login-NonInteractive technical profile.
2. According to  [Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#register-identity-experience-framework-applications)

> Azure AD B2C requires you to register two applications that it uses to
> sign up and sign in users with local accounts:
> IdentityExperienceFramework, a web API, and
> ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework, a native app with delegated
> permission to the IdentityExperienceFramework app. Your users can sign
> up with an email address or username and a password to access your
> tenant-registered applications, which creates a "local account." Local
> accounts exist only in your Azure AD B2C tenant.

3. Also  don’t forget to update  with the Application (client) IDs of the two applications you registered when completing adding, IdentityExperienceFramework and ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework.
4. Also see to add emailaddress  into the identities collection .

```js
        { 
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
          "issuerAssignedId": "xyz@yahoo.com"
        },
```

Please check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696099/error-70001-trying-to-sign-in-as-azure-ad-b2c-user-with-custom-identity-experien?rq=1)

**References:**

1. [Azure AD B2C missing email claim with local account and user id
   sign-in - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67781096/azure-ad-b2c-missing-email-claim-with-local-account-and-user-id-sign-in)
2. [Invalid usename or password when sigining local account with Azure
   AD B2C Custom Policy - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303500/invalid-usename-or-password-when-sigining-local-account-with-azure-ad-b2c-custom?rq=1)